# SSIS result set to WHERE IN clause?

Tags: ssis

I have a Execute SQL Task object which executes a simple SELECT script which will return around 30k rows and 1 column. I successfully assign its result to a variable. How can I use those result set to Data flow Task OLEDBConnection to WHERE IN clause?

My reason for this is I am not allowed to create a linked server and create tables even on tmp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example you can use:
[image]

Simply change your query to be "**WHERE IN(?)**" and click on the **Parameters...** button on the right to map your parameter to the variable you stored your result set in. In my case, the variable I'm using is a date which I use to filter the query by in the where clause at the bottom.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. This would help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'Merge Join' task in the Data Flow to combine data (Inner/Left/Full Join) from queries across multiple servers.
Use the MRGJ task to recreate an inner join that previously required a linked server.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. but i cannot use merge join, Im trying to cut down the data to be validated.